# Are good CSS design and IE6 / IE7 support mutually exclusive?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, standards-compliance

Like every web developer, I usually curse the creators of IE6 with foul and untimely deaths at least once a week. Yet my company requires me to keep supporting that most-hated of browsers.

My problem today has been wanting to first use a wildcard in my CSS and then trying to use the "inherit" property instead. Neither of which are supported by IE7-.

I really, REALLY want to have good, well-structured, properly-inheriting CSS (object-oriented CSS, if you like that buzzword) but I have that sinking feeling in the pit of my stomach that sooner or later, it's going to have to be custom-purpose and location-based classes.

This poses the question: given how utterly awful IE is at handling many CSS concepts, is it impossible to adequately support this browser at the same time as having a well-structured CSS document?

Just to clarify: I'm aware that there are plenty of ways (some legitimate, some less so) to get around the bugs and shortcomings found in IE6 and 7. What I'm really asking is "if you want to have a single, well-written stylesheet that inherits correctly, must you choose between that and having a consistent look across all browsers?". Hope that makes sense.

In other words, should I stick to my principles and code a good style sheet or should I accept that IE6 still enjoys a horribly high (20% on last count) market share and bring myself to support it? Or is there some happy medium that allows me to minimise the frankenstein surgery on my HTML and CSS while still achieving some respectable results in IE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be fair, you can't blame it all on IE (though Microsoft certainly is by far the worst transgressor). Part of the problem with such large & rapidly-evolving standards is that it's too much of a moving target to be perfectly implemented in a timely fashion. Unfortunately, the release cycles of web browsers do not coincide with the release of new web specifications. So all browser developers can do is try to implement as many features as they can from the latest W3C recommendations, selecting what *they think* will be the most commonly used features to implement first.

However, things are clearly improving, and it *is* possible to support IE6/7 and still use proper CSS design. It's just... difficult. Take a look at [this comparison of layout engines & CSS support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_support). If you look at the overall trend, you'll see that most browsers (even IE) do tend to comply with established standards in the long-run, it just takes some browsers longer than others to implement a standard after its introduction.

And sometimes it's not that one browser is "less" standards-compliant than another. With new standards the problem is often that different development teams chose to adopt *different parts* of the new specification. So even though CSS3 is already beginning to be implemented by most browsers, we'll probably have to wait until CSS4 is published before seeing consistent support across all major rendering engines. And if you try to use the latest CSS3 features right now, you'll have a hard time establishing compatibility across all major browsers. But if you're using features introduced in CSS1, it's no problem at all.

Therefore, the only option--aside from using ugly CSS hacks--is to stick with well-established *older* specifications. Then the problem is no longer ***trying to conform to web standards while supporting a particular browser***. Instead the problem simply becomes ***trying to resist the urge to use the latest & greatest CSS features***.

Aside from that, the only permanent solution I see to this recurring situation is for the W3C to **prioritize** different parts of newly introduced specifications so that the new features can be implemented in discrete phases synchronized across all the major browsers. So, for instance, grammar rules might be given the highest priority along with a set deadline for its implementation. After that would come the second phase, which could be element & attribute selectors, and so on and so forth.

This would require a tremendous level of cooperation between the W3C and development teams, but it would be worth it. After all, it does users and web developers no good for IE to implement one subset of features from CSS3 while Firefox implements a different subset and the Webkit browsers yet another subset. A "standard" is no good until it's actually *standardized* across all the major rendering platforms. **It's better for each browser to support fewer new features but have them all be *the same features*, than for them to separately introduce a ton of their own features that aren't universally supported.**

Comment: Great answer. I like this. I would agree that it seems to be a matter of time for vendors to pick up and agree on the interpretation of a given standard. MS have been notoriously bad for that in the past, but seem to be improving. Falling back to the established standards is good sense, although not always easy in practice.

Comment: The problem is when older standards aren't coherent crossbrowser either. Unless you work with positioning 1px gifs and tables, you can't get the exact same rendering on different browsers. The interesting thing is that you *shouldn't try to get the same rendering to the pixel*. Let the browser do it's magic and the user resize *your* design to *his* needs.

Answer (score 3):

Not at all - you can compensate for IE's shortcomings with [conditional comments](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/cc-plus.html) and an IE specific stylesheet, while serving your 'nice' stylesheet to other browsers.

Something else which I find helps is to use a [CSS reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/). While this isn't going to resolve all of IE's issues, it does give you a good baseline to work from.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the idealist part of me that has been trying to accomplish everything all in one stylesheet. While I fully respect the use of conditionals, I've just been trying to avoid them as I feel they're ugly and make maintenance that little bit more complicated.
May have to face reality, regrettably.

Comment: The alternative is to rely on css hacks which I think is even uglier. Conditional comments are the lesser of two evils.

Comment: You don't need to make a full css for IE. I've found that I can correct my styles with just a few lines (10 - 50 lines) on a separate IE targeted css file to compensate it's box model. On the other hand, css hacks are *generaly* Evil.

Answer (score 1):

The most anoying IE6 *feature* is it's box model handling. You should stick to margin instead when positioning boxes, and try to use relative font sizes to allow font resizing on IE. The rest of the quirks are [well documented](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

Using [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) is the cleanest way of having both a clean style sheet for well behaving browsers, and still using being beautiful on IE. This is what I use, only needing 1 css file of a few lines to repair my sites look and feel.

The *dark* path of crossbrowser consistent look & feel are [css hacks](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks), but I strongly discourage it's use, specialy now that for some time we'll have to target three different IE (6, 7 & 8)

Normally, if you get the style to work in both FF and Chrome/Safari, IE is only a few corrections away of being correct.

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree entirely about using hacks.  Definitely plan to stay away from that approach. No good can come of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great site [Position Is Everything](http://www.positioniseverything.net/) that details how FF, IE and Safari conform to standard CSS.  At the site you will find most of the workarounds / cures for IE that will alleviate the need for you to write so much conditional code for your CSS.

You'll  also want to check out [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) for more on CSS and IE.  There are also great articles on tableless layout with CSS, handling the height bug in IE, etc.  Good luck - IE 6 really sucks when it comes CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not. If you ensure that they render the page in "standards" mode as opposed to "quirks" mode many of the common IE CSS issues are resolved. To do this you must provide a valid doctype statement at the top of the page, such as

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

As others have pointed out, another good idea is to start off your stylesheet with a snippet that removes all paddings and margins like so:

```
*,html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Finally, one common problem with CSS based layouts in IE is that clearing of floats doesn't happen when you'd expect. This is to do with a hidden object property in IE called "hasLayout"; only objects that "have layout" will correctly wrap around and enclose floated child objects. It is easy to ensure that your containers "have layout" simply by specifying at least one dimension for them:

```
height: 1%;
width: 100%;
zoom: 1;
```

I do not personally use conditional IE stylesheets except for one single thing: to replace PNG backgrounds with GIFs in IE < 7 - there is nothing wrong with using them, I just find it unnescessarily complicates things when you have to define the appearance of the same object in two different places. With the three tips above and a bit of patience you should be able to create CSS based layouts using a single stylesheet that render just as well in IE 6/7 as they do in Mozilla/Webkit.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

IE 6 really does limit what we can do.

It’s the lack of support for advanced selectors (and inherit — IE 7 doesn’t support that either) that gets me. Just having the child selector and attribute selectors would be nice, that’d really cut down the amount of code we have to write and maintain. You can only work around the lack of support for them by duplicating your styles, so you just end up having to code as if they didn’t exist.

Sigh.

Answer (score -1):

Only follow online CSS tutorials that is rendered correctly with IE6 and Chrome (or Webkit). If it looks right in both, it likely looks right in (almost) all browsers.